# SQL query to get count of rows with more than one row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Within my application, I have a set of filters that can be applied when listing resources, which builds up a query by adding WHERE clauses, etc. before executing the query.  This is using SQL Server 2008.

I have two pertinent tables, one which contains some static data about the resource, and another which can contain arbitrary/optional fields pertaining to that resource.

First table is something like this (table names & fields changed):

```
CREATE TABLE Resources (
    ResID       varbinary(28),

    ... extra stuff omitted

    type        integer );
```

The second table just has name/value pairs and the corresponding resource ID

```
CREATE TABLE ResourceFields (
    ResID       varbinary(28) NOT NULL,

    Name        nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Value       nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL);
```

So, for this example, there could be multiple rows in 'ResourceFields' with name = 'ContactName' for the same ResID.

**What I want to do is get a count of the number of rows in the 'Resources' table that have more than one 'ContactName' listed in 'ResourceFields' with 'type' equal to some value.**

I came up with this (don't laugh -- I know just enough SQL to cause problems)

```
SELECT count(r.ResID) 
    FROM Resources as r 
        INNER JOIN ResourceFields AS rf 
            ON rf.ResID = r.ResID 
                AND rf.name = 'ContactName' 
    WHERE r.type = 1 
    GROUP BY rf.ResID 
    HAVING COUNT(rf.Value) > 1;
```

but instead of returning the count of the number of rows (43 in my test set) in 'Resources', I get all the COUNT(rf.Value) values returned (that is, 43 individual counts).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use your original query as a derived table (put it in a subselect):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS C
    FROM Resources as r 
        INNER JOIN ResourceFields AS rf 
            ON rf.ResID = r.ResID 
                AND rf.name = 'ContactName' 
    WHERE r.type = 1 
    GROUP BY rf.ResID 
    HAVING COUNT(rf.Value) > 1;
) s
```

Comment: He might actually want a `SUM()` of the inner `count`, but otherwise I like this.

Comment: Yes, he definitely might. So far, however, he has stated that he expected to obtain the value `43`, but got 43 rows of values instead.

Comment: No, I just want the count.  I'll try this out.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the trailing 's' for?

Comment: it is the (in this case unneeded) name of the subselect (like in AS s) - if you for example wanted to join that with something else you can use s to access the subselect columns (in this case just C)...

Comment: @Shawn D: SQL Server requires subselects to be aliased, even if the subselect is the only object that you are pulling columns from. Likewise, the inner `COUNT(*)` expression must be aliased, even if you do not actually care about this column's values. Not all subqueries *must* always be aliased, but derived tables in particular must.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really familiar with SQL Server but try:

```
SELECT count( r.ResID ) FROM Resources as r where 1 < (select count(rf.value) from ResourceFields AS rf where rf.ResID = r.ResID AND rf.name = 'ContactName') and r.type = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pre-aggregate the count of the 'ContactName' attributes.  This is perhaps most easily accomplished with a CTE:

```
WITH Multiple_Contacts (ResID) as (SELECT a.ResID
                                   FROM Resources as a
                                   JOIN ResourceFields as B
                                   ON b.ResID = A.ResID
                                   AND b.name = 'ContactName'
                                   WHERE a.type = 1
                                   GROUP BY a.ResID
                                   HAVING COUNT(a.ResId) > 1)
SELECT COUNT(ResId)
FROM Multiple_Contacts
```

Some other things to consider -
Possibly make `name` in `ResourceFields` actually be a foreign key to a different table (so changing all attributes to a different text name is trivial).  This would also allow you to put information about the expected format of data in `value` in the referenced table, hopefully limiting invalid data (using regex masks, etc.) - you have to be extremely careful with multi-domain tables like this (generally, they shouldn't be used, but there are probably some use-cases).
Also, are you really anticipating storing 28 *bytes* worth of different resources?  This is a rather large number... (remember that an Int is usually 4 bytes, and stores about 4 billion different values).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Resources as r
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ResourceFields rf
    WHERE rf.ResId = r.ResId
    AND rf.name = 'ContactName'
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
AND r.type = 1
```

UPDATE: Grouping removed from the subquery, which added irrelevant rows to the count.

Comment: This actually came back with a count of 79, so I think it's doubly including some rows in the subquery.

Comment: Yes I based too much on the exiting query. Now it should work as expected.